# Saving a Dictionary to File While keeping it as a Dictionary

Tags: python, file

```
itemsInExistence = []
item = {}
item['name'] = input("What do you want the new item to be called? ")
item['stats'] = int(input("What is its stat? "))
item['rank'] = int(input("What is its base rank? "))
item['amount'] = int(input("How many of it are there? "))
for i in range(item['amount']):
  itemsInExistence.append(item)
def save_list2():
  with open('itemsleft.txt', 'wb') as f:
  i = 0
  for item in itemsInExistence:
    pickle.dump(itemsInExistence, f)
    i += 1
```

I tried to save it both normally and with pickle, but neither keeps the dictionary's values. I need to save the dictionary to the file and retrieve it from the file with 'stats', 'rank', 'amount' still being integers and still separate from the rest of the line. (Keep in mind that there will be more than one saved item in itemsInExistence, both to be saved and loaded.)

```
def save_list2():
  ii = 0
  for i in itemsInExistence:
    d = itemsInExistence[ii]
    json.dump(d, open(files2, 'w'))
    ii += 1 

def load_list2():
    with open(files2,'r') as a:
      for line in a:
        line = line.strip()
        itemsInExistence.append(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `JSON` format to store a dict into a file, it's quite easy

```
import json

file = "foofile"
d = dict()
# fill d

# save data : format the dict to a string and it into the file
json.dump(d, open(file, 'w'))

# read data : read the file's content and parse to a dict
a = json.load(open(file))
```

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: I get a giant error when trying to use this code. I cannot copy it, and It would take forever to copy by hand. I don't understand a word of it. But it basically says that it doesn't like a = json.load(open(file))

Comment: I am using repl.it to make all my programs. It doesn't let you copy errors for some reason.

Comment: I will post what I have for your saving method below my question code.

Comment: Oh lol that is the error, there is no load. --Edit: Nvm that isn't the error. It is giving me 'utf-8' codec cannot decode byte 0x80 in position 0.